# What's wrong in my regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I need to get from the line below only these parts: Jony, Smith and example-free@wpdevelop.com

which, as you can see, they are between ^ and ~.

```
text^name1^Jony~text^secondname1^Smith~text^email1^example-free@wpdevelop.com~
```

to do this I tried:

```
preg_match_all ('/\^(.*?)\~/', $row['form'], $res);
```

For the name it displays: **^name1^Jony~**
for the second name: **^secondname1^Smith~**
and email: **^email1^example-free@wpdevelop.com~**

As you can see the word "text" has already disappeared, but not the ^, name1, secondname1, email1 and ~

Can you tell me what's wrong in my regular expression?

Comment: Could you please provide some more sample data? Otherwise it would be easier to explode by `^` and `~` and get the values out of an array.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do a 2-stage `explode()` on `~` and then `^`?

Comment: or even easier: preg_split("/\~|\^/", $data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs to be `'/\^([^\^]*?)\~/'`,you're using `.`, which selects `^`. You need to not select `^` using `[^\^]` rather than `.`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! :) I added [^\~] to remove ~ Is this right : '/\^([^\^]*?)([^\~])/'

Comment: No, you're selecting the ~ now as well, you want it to be `/\^([^\^]*?)[^~]/`

Answer (score 3):

change `.*` to `[^^]*` meaning "Any character *excluding* `^`"

```
<?php
$str = 'text^name1^Jony~text^secondname1^Smith~text^email1^example-free@wpdevelop.com~';

preg_match_all ('/\^([^^]*?)\~/', $str, $res);

var_dump($res);

/*
//output 

$ php scratch.php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "^Jony~"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "^Smith~"
    [2]=>
    string(28) "^example-free@wpdevelop.com~"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Jony"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    [2]=>
    string(26) "example-free@wpdevelop.com"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: preg_match_all ('/\^([^^]*?)\(?:~)/', $str, $res);

Answer (score 1):

This is better:

```
<?php

$string = 'text^name1^Jony~text^secondname1^Smith~text^email1^example-free@wpdevelop.com~';

preg_match_all('/\^.+?\^(.+?)~/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The result in $matches will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "^name1^Jony~"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "^secondname1^Smith~"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "^email1^example-free@wpdevelop.com~"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Jony"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    [2]=>
    string(26) "example-free@wpdevelop.com"
  }
}
```

I added this .+?\^ part to the regular expression, it matches the text between the two ^ characters.